# $\log_5 {(x+1)} - \log _4 {(x-2)} = 1$

Tags: logarithms

I tried to solve this equation by changing bases.

$\dfrac {\log_4 (x+1)}{\log_4 5} = \log_4 (4x -8)$

$.86 \log_4 (x+1) = \log_4 (4x-8)$

Then i got stuck.
Please share your idea with me.

Comment: @What does it mean .86 there?

Comment: @Navaro It's $\dfrac {1}{\log_4 5}$

Comment: Next step: $\log_4(x+1)^{0.86}=\log_4(4x-8)$ $$\\$$ Then this: $4^{\log_4(4x-8)}=(x+1)^{0.86}$ $$\\$$ Which simplifies to this: $4x-8=(x+1)^{0.86}$

Comment: @LanierFreeman I doubt you can solve that sort of equation analytically

Comment: @Ovi and I doubt this logarithm can be solved using elementary methods. Considering the OP used a calculator for $\frac{1}{\log_45}$, I figured it might at least be worth a comment, if only to show why the problem is presenting, well, a problem.

Comment: That's Exactly the way i did after that.

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments, I do not think that there is any hope for an analytical solution and numerical methods need to be considered.

Using natural logarithms, the equation write $$\frac{\log (x+1)}{\log (5)}-\frac{\log (x-2)}{\log (4)}=1$$ So, let us consider the function $$f(x)=\frac{\log (x+1)}{\log (5)}-\frac{\log (x-2)}{\log (4)}-1$$ By inspection, $f(3)=\frac{\log (4)}{\log (5)}-1\approx -0.138647$ so the solution is close to $x=3$ (the function being tending to infinity when $x\to 2$).

Probably the simplest method would be Newton starting with $x_0=3$. This would generates the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n &  x_n \\
 1 & 2.75504680789501165 \\
 2 & 2.78640480505808886 \\
 3 & 2.78717999430163650 \\
 4 & 2.78718044253601188 \\
 5 & 2.78718044253616154  
\end{array}
\right)$$